# Clustered vertical lines in the plot(model, residuals)

Tags: data-visualization, residuals, model, glmmtmb

I am stuck in the diagnostics of my model, and I am looking for advice on what to do.

My data frame goes like this

```
 $ ID      : Factor w/ 15 levels "Buzinza","Kabukojo",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Period  : Factor w/ 3 levels "After","Before",..: 1 3 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ Class   : Factor w/ 3 levels "Adult female",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ no.trans: num  4 5 6 4 15 4 17 22 2 23 ...
```

Nbinom had a better AIC than Poisson (which was overdispersed)

```
model_nb <- glmmTMB(no.trans ~ Period * Class + (1 | ID),
                    family = nbinom2(),
                    data = periods)
```

Normality and overdispersion were ok.
Vif was not sensible so I calculated the variance of predictor variables and the matrix seemed ok.

But  `plot(fitted(model_nb), resid)` showed vertical clustered lines.
[image]

Dharma accused the presence of 12 outliers in 3465 observations for the non-transformed data and 6 outliers for the sqr transformed data.

I tried also lme4 package.

I have only those variables so I cannot complicate the model further. And it is already quite simple.

Not sure what to do next, any advice would be very welcomed!

Cheers,

Comment: Looks fine to me, what is the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't be showing a random scattering of points instead of the vertical patterns? This is my first time working with count data. Is this normal for this type of data?

Comment: You have only factors as predictors, so there is only a limited number of values that your model can predict, hence vertical lines

Comment: Thank you!! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @rep_ho Why not add that as an answer?

Comment: @mkt good point

Answer (score 3):

In this case vertical lines are expected. You have only factors as predictors, so there is only a limited number of values that your model will produce as predictions; hence the small set of vertical lines on your plot.